# Getting rid of numbers in a json response ( LARAVEL 9 )

Tags: php, json, laravel

i'm having some problems with my json response.

When I make an api call from a user (id:1) it returns the response well, but if i change the user (f.e id:2) it returns it with some identifiers on it. Any idea?

Response from id:1

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "matricula": "222555999C",
            "capacidad": "220",
            "created_at": "2022-04-06T09:52:39.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-06T09:52:39.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "transportista": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Response from id:2

```json
{
    "data": {
        "3"(<--- this is the problem): {
            "id": 9,
            "matricula": "HYK 2024",
            "capacidad": "100",
            "created_at": "2022-04-08T15:12:22.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T15:12:22.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "transportista": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT 1

This is how I am getting the response:

```
public function getCamiones(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $camiones = Camiones::all()->where('transportista',$id);
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $camiones,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're creating the response?

Comment: Please, do not do `Camiones::all()->where('transportista',$id);` as you are getting everything and then filtering... that could be huge and run out of memory, and it will still take a lot of time... do this `Camiones::where('transportista',$id)->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're getting all of the results, then filtering the collection returned, instead of having the database do the work for you. Instead, grab only a single row.

```
$camiones = Camiones::where('transportista', $id)->first();
```

To get all the rows that match, then you need

```
$camiones = Camiones::where('transportista', $id)->get();
```

Comment: I need all results, not a single row. I'm getting a collection of objects which got the same user ID. Getting a single row would only return 1 of these objects, right?

Comment: I was wondering about that since you were only showing a single row. You would change it to `get()` to get all the rows that match

Comment: Removing ::all made it for me. Thanks! Could you explain me why it was doing that thing?

Comment: Using `all()`, then `->where()` means that you're getting all of the rows, storing it a Laravel collection, then filtering the results with `where`. Doing that can add keys to the results. Doing `where` then `get` means that the database does the filtering for you, then just stores it into a collection.

Comment: It worked very well for me so thanks for answering the question! Didn't know that from ::all.